# Rescue : Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on localhost:6379

Tags: redis, resque

I have followed the instructions to install resque, but now when I try to spawn a worker with this command I get a connection error:

```
$ QUEUE=mailer rake environment resque:work --trace
```

this is the error that I get:

> Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on localhost:6379

Comment: looks like the redis server isn't running

Comment: Server Fault has a canonical question about [Connection Refused](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message).

Answer (score 55):

Have you verified redis-server is running? Please don't ask me to dissect the following command, but in a terminal you can type:

`ps aux | grep redis`

You should then see something like:

`redis    13319  0.0  0.0   2884  1056 ?        Ss   10:54   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf`

If it's not running, I recommend issuing the following command:

`nohup redis-server &`

That will start a redis-server process and detach it from the terminal. Otherwise I believe you need to leave that terminal open the entire time you want redis-server to be running.

(Always a good idea to verify the process is running once you fire it up, so use that first command once more.)

Update: I'm not sure if this works for all versions, but on Redis Server 3.0.6 on Ubuntu 16.04, you can issue `sudo service redis-server status` as well. You'll receive some verbose output, so I'll not post it all, but that may be another option for some of us.

Answer (score 15):

Have you installed redis?

Installing REDIS on Ubuntu

Ref: http://redis.io/download

1. Download, extract and compile Redis with:-

   ```
   $ cd ~/Installations
   $ curl -O http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.2.1.tar.gz
   $ tar xzf redis-2.2.1.tar.gz
   $ cd redis-2.2.1
   $ sudo make
   ```
2. Install Tcl (the Tool Command Language) runtime

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install tcl8.5
   ```
3. Running Redis Server

   ```
   $ src/redis-server
   [31371] 24 Feb 10:14:03 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to   specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
   [31371] 24 Feb 10:14:03 * Server started, Redis version 2.2.1
   [31371] 24 Feb 10:14:03 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may  fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
   [31371] 24 Feb 10:14:03 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
   ```

Answer (score 11):

just do it:- `sudo apt-get install redis-server`

Answer (score 4):

Use `redis-server` to Start the server and then use `redis-cli ping` to test if the server is up. You should receive a pong if the server is started. This was taken straight from the docs. [enter link description here](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the "127.0.0.1:6379" instead "localhost:6379" for connecting to redis.
so, wherever you want to connect the redis, use the redis-server ip.

Comment: It seems that the redis port has nothing to do with HTTP port.  The 127.0.0.1 is HTTP localhost.

Comment: @YanKingYin localhost is a FQDN. On most computers, it translates to 127.0.0.1 in IPv4 or ::1 in IPv6. So, it's not related to HTTP or other protocols.